How to force linq to Excel to read a column as string
I am using linqToExcel to read some .csv files and put in a table.
var excelFile = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(file);

var result = (from row in excelFile.Worksheet(0)
              let item = new IncomingPayments
              {
                  Code = row["Code"].Cast<string>(),
                  Name = row["Name"].Cast<string>(),
                  CustomerCode = row["CustomerCode"].Cast<string>(),
                  Amount = row["Amount"].Cast<double>(),
                  Type = row["Type"].Cast<string>(),                    
              }
              select item).ToList();

An example of the data I am reading:

Problem is that when I get to the rows where the A & B column has a dash, they all return as null. Seems like linqToExcel assumes the colums are int, even when I cast as string. How can I avoid this and get this to work properly?

If you have csv files why not just use something like CsvHelper?

If you cannot define the column types, perhaps a quick fix could be to add an empty space to the end of the value so Excel reads it as a string?

@Guru Stron. I have used that instead.
